# Taipy deployment through Apache WSGI

Tags: apache, wsgi, taipy

I'm exploring Taipy and looks very promising but I was wondering if it is possible to run it in an Ubuntu Server with a LAMP setup? I'm already running flask applications there.

Best regards,
Carlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the documentation on how to deploy in different ways Taipy [here](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/run-deploy/deploy/). The deployment in the doc is for *gunicorn* and *nginx*, but it is similar.

Taipy is based on Flask. So, if you need the Flask app to deploy it, you can get back the Flask app used by Taipy from the Gui object:

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui 

gui = Gui('# Taipy app')
gui.run(run_server=False)
flask_app = gui.get_flask_app()
```